# Pi Compute Module, can I leave the unuse DAC reference and output pins floating?

Tags: video, composite-video

Am designing my own daughter board using Compute Module.

Since I not going to use the RCA video out (DAC portion), can I neglect putting a 2.5V regulator, leaving these pins (DAC_2V5, DAC_OUT & DAC_TERM) floating?

Will leaving DAC_2V5 reference voltage floating caused any instability to the processor?